# Numpy sometimes fails to load when imported from embedded Python called from a C++ program on Win11

Tags: python, c++, numpy, windows-11

I have a C++ program that calls Python with a module that indirectly imports numpy on Win11.  If I copy the executable to the Python environment (in my case, c:\users\jim\miniconda3), it works.  If I run a copy in another directory, I get the following error:

C:\Users\jim\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py:127: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service

A significant difference between the two cases is the Python sys.path.  The sys.path from the executable copied to the miniconda directory contains:

```
C:\users\jim\miniconda3\python39.zip
```

(which, not incidentally, does not exist), while the executable in a different directory has a sys.path that contains:

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\python39.zip
```

(which does exist).  If I take ASWCLIV2 out of the system path, my program works everywhere.

I have two questions:  First, what is going on here?  And second, how can I prevent this short of removing AWSCLIV2 from they system path?